# Is it possible to install javascript plugin using an .msa package installation on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, desktop-application, browser-plugin

I have developed a simple javascript plugin which is not deployed to any web stores. Is it possible to implement the same plugin to an desktop application installer to install the plugins to browser along with that desktop application installation process?

Anyone please help